# Draw a line between 2 points chart js

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I have some arranged data in the chart , and want to connect two or more when a button is clicked ..
I have extracted the x and y positions from the chart metadata , but now I want to draw a line between 2 of these points ..
I tried to draw over the canvas , but the line immediately disappears when I move the mouse .
Should I draw another canvas over the previous one ?
if yes , how can I do this ?

```
    meta = mh.chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
    p1 ={x: meta.data[2]._model.x,y: meta.data[2]._model.y};
    p2 ={x: meta.data[10]._model.x,y: meta.data[10]._model.y};
```

in the code , i want to draw a line between p1 and p2 .
of course the values is changeable dynamically

Comment: Add your code if you want people to be able to answer.